# What kind of technology does twilio use?

Tags: api, twilio

I use the twilio api to send/receive sms messages and http requests, given a free account, a paid twilio number, and paying something like 0.075 cents per message.

I'm wondering: what kind of technology is twilio built on?

At minimum I'm curious:
1. How are they registering their phone numbers?
2. How do they convert between the sms protocol and the http protocol 
3. Where can I read more about this?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilio#Technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio uses Amazon Web Services to host telephony infrastructure and provide connectivity between HTTP and the public switched telephone network (PSTN) through its APIs.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilio#Technology